# DOMDocument::load(): Attribute xmlns redefined in Laravel

Tags: laravel, domdocument

I'm creating an SEO system. Everything works fine except for a few websites.

I'm using **Laravel 5.4 and DomDocument**

When i try to scan it it gives me **this error**:

```
ErrorException in ScanController.php line 252:
DOMDocument::load(): Attribute xmlns redefined in /seo/public/tempxml/result.xml, line: 3
```

**ScanController line 252:**

```
$dom->load('tempxml/result.xml');
```

**result.xml line 3:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="nl" lang="nl" xml:lang="nl"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta name="description" content="agrarisch handels en hulpbedrijf, handelsonderneming in Vlagtwedde en Mussel (Kopstukken). Alles voor tuin en park hobby doe het zelf dier en tuin." /><meta name="keywords" content="machines, ter apel, beregening, grasmaaier, zitmaaiers, bosmaaier, trimmer, kettingzaag" /><title>website</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.website.nl/wp-content/themes/website/style.css" /><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.website.nl/wp-content/themes/website/assets/js/backstretch.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.website.nl/wp-content/themes/website/assets/js/easySlider1.7.js"></script><!--[if lt IE 7]>
```

What is the problem here? As i said, other websites works perfectly but this one doesn't.

Comment: obviously you have twice `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`, what is the other content of your `result.xml` ? I see only **HTML** in the code that you post :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering my question. Sorry for not answering.. I've never seen your reply. I found out the problem is the result line 3. Normally a website doesn't use xmlns. How would i change this in dom?